# Twitter follow Drupal

Tags: views, blocks

I want to show a list of Twitter users who is following a post, with a button that allows the users to follow them. The list should appear as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried using the Twitter, and oAuth modules but I had no luck, so far.

Comment: Source for above image, apparently from Quora: http://www.quora.com/Drupal-CMS/Has-the-Twitter-module-for-Drupal-6-been-modified-so-it-works-again-after-Twitter-recently-switched-to-oauth-only/followers

Comment: Links for you: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the output image above you are trying to create a widget that would show a select number of twitter users from either your own followers or from a specific list, etc. I would suggest that this is not a Drupal issue or at least you shouldn't try and treat it as one. You could do this by creating a content type and outputting it as a view using a view template, etc. but thats a lot of database overhead for data that will likely be changing frequently.

The better way to do this is to use a jQuery / javascript plugin that will pull the data as a json file from your source (either a followers feed or your list feed from twitter) and output it directly. You can use any number of existing plugins and widgets available online for this, ex. this one:

http://twittercounter.com/pages/buttons

or roll your own, but further details would be out of scope for this site.

Finally, I'd recommend that you take a look at the site you got that image from first and see if you can figure out what widget it is using, I'd bet that they are using an open widget / plugin that you can then just copy for your own site.